# I don't understand this email from Facebook about my app

Tags: facebook, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dec 5th beaking changes - facebook says app will be effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587728/dec-5th-beaking-changes-facebook-says-app-will-be-effect)

I got an email that my app is impacting some new rules. Unfortunately english isn't my native language and I found no possibility to ask the facebook support - I'm not sure if I understood the email correctly. I hope you can help me:

> Your desktop web game hosted primarily off Facebook currently
>   accesses user connections when authenticating and/or requests
>   additional permissions beyond age, email, and publishing permissions.
>   This is no longer allowed per Facebook Platform Policy I.13a:
>
> Desktop web games off of Facebook.com may only use Facebook Login
>   (Authentication, excluding user connections such as friend list),
>   Social Plugins and publishing (e.g., Feed Dialog, Stream Publish, or
>   Open Graph). When authenticating, these games may not request
>   additional permissions other than age, email, and our Publishing
>   Permissions.
>
> If your app is accessing user connections
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) or asking
>   for additional permissions beyond age, email, and our Publishing
>   Permissions, please remove these requests. After December 5th, we will
>   place restrictions on your app if your app continues to access user
>   connections or request additional permissions other than
>   'user_birthday', 'email' or our publishing permissions such as
>   'publish_actions' or 'publish_stream'.

Do I understand this right, I can ask for following additional permission like email or publishing stream but nothing else?

I changed my login-url from 
"scope=email,publish_stream,read_stream,user_games_activity" 
to this: 
"scope=email,publish_stream" 
Is it now okay?

I also use $facebook->api('/'.$FacebookID.'/friends'); to get the list of friends and build a form where the user can send his friends an invitation. Is this not alowed anymore?

> • Your Canvas/mobile game currently shares the same app ID with a
>   desktop web game off Facebook.com, which is no longer allowed per
>   Facebook Platform Policy I.13b:
>
> (Games on Facebook.com and mobile must not share the same app ID with
>   desktop web games off of Facebook.com. You must not use Canvas apps to
>   promote or link to game sites off of Facebook, and must not use emails
>   obtained from us to promote or link to desktop web games off of
>   Facebook.com).
>
> Please create a separate app ID for your Facebook Connect integration.
>   After December 5th, your Connect app will no longer be accessible if
>   it continues to share an app ID with its Canvas/mobile counterpart.
>
> You have received this message because your app uses a Connect
>   integration. If you believe this to be an error, please reference the
>   developer docs to ensure your app is categorized correctly.

This one I don't understand at all. What and where can I do that? My app has a own URL and a canvas page at facebook. Would it be enough to remove the canvas page and only keep the direct URL?

Answer (score 0):

> I changed my login-url from "scope=email,publish_stream,read_stream,user_games_activity" to this: "scope=email,publish_stream" Is it now okay?

Yes, it should be ok now because according to the breaking changes "these games may not request additional permissions other than age, email, and our Publishing Permissions." So you should be fine.

> I also use $facebook->api('/'.$FacebookID.'/friends'); to get the list of friends and build a form where the user can send his friends an invitation. Is this not alowed anymore?

`/friends` doesn't require any additional permissions, so I *think* it should be ok.

> What and where can I do that? My app has a own URL and a canvas page at facebook. Would it be enough to remove the canvas page and only keep the direct URL?

Yes, you need to separate your canvas/mobile game from the desktop web game.  Currently, they both have the same app ID, you can choose to either remove the canvas page entirely or create a new app for the canvas/mobile game and use that new app ID.  Regardless, the end result is that only one of your games can use your exisiting app ID.